# Format the MediaStore.Video.MHi,edia.DURATION into hours and second

Tags: android

I using a managedQuery to query my device for videos. The milli-seconds returned for MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION are formated using a function that i have written. This is as

```
            Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(milliseconds));
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    return df.format(d);
```

But the format returned from this is returned. I directly pass the value returned form the cursor to this. Any help here ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

The default value forr MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION is 0. When the video is copied to sdcard the duration is not automatically calculated. An app must update the MediaStore db record with a valid duration value if it knows it.